# issue when ssh-ing to ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am getting the following error:

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/shopious.pem ubuntu@54.245.124.178


OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.245.124.178 [54.245.124.178] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya15417/.ssh/shopious.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/aditya15417/.ssh/shopious.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 66:b7:fd:11:91:1b:bd:a2:b0:58:48:5d:b9:3b:e1:14
debug1: Host '54.245.124.178' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/aditya15417/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/aditya15417/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/aditya15417/.ssh/shopious.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
```

This command used to work, but now it no longer works. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Move your .pem file to home folder or any other location other then .ssh. I hope its conflicting with the system's private key. Also delete the known_hosts file from the .ssh folder and make sure you have run chmod 400 shopious.pem so that it should not have write or execute permissions. In case if its not working, let me know